# Faster accessing local variables vs member variables?

Tags: c++, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ performance of accessing member variables versus local variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238535/c-performance-of-accessing-member-variables-versus-local-variables)

I was always under the impression it was much faster to access local variables on the stack, than it was to access member variables (these are the same as global variables yeh?). However, I came across this post: [C++ performance of accessing member variables versus local variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238535/c-performance-of-accessing-member-variables-versus-local-variables) where it was claimed in the accepted answer that there is practically no difference?

Now I am confused because my whole understanding was that local variables are quicker to access??

Comment: Looks like you missed all the warnings at the top. Go back and read them again.

Comment: I also don't understand why reading that answer doesn't answer your question. What are you asking here that isn't already covered there? This "question" looks more like you're inviting discussion, rather than asking a question. The question has already been asked and answered.

Comment: I guess, the stack is an implementation detail and still both local and member variables are stored in memory and would assume that the instructions required to access them are same.

Comment: Member variables are *not* like globals. In fast, for objects on the stack, they are also on the stack. Any why would globals be slower? They can be in cache just like any other storage location. Performance is not a reason to avoid globals (it's no reason to use them either).

Comment: Executive summary: Local variables are accessed relative to the stack pointer, member variables are accessed relative to the `this` pointer. No practical difference.