# C variables preserved in struct or local?

Tags: c

I am running a code on a DSP processor, so the resources are limited. 
I am puzzled wether some arrays should be placed in the object structs, or be made local vars in the subroutines. Like so:

**Case 1**, array in the object struct:

```
typedef struct
{
   int var1;
   int var2;
   int array[1000];
   // etc...
} obj1;    

sub1( obj1* o1)
{
   o1->array[x] = ... ;
}
```

**Case 2**, array as local variable:

```
typedef struct
{
   int var1;
   int var2;
} obj1;     

sub1( obj1* o1)
{
   int array[1000];
   array[x] = ... ;
}
```

Main loop would look like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    while(1) 
    {
        obj1 o1;
        sub1( &o1 );

        obj2 o2;
        sub2( &o2 );

        obj3 o3;
        sub3( &o3 );

        // etc...    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Arrays are NOT reused, so they can be local.
However, is there any advantage in Case 2 when compared to Case 1?

Comment: If the array is purely local, the use case 2. Why would you want to put the array into the struct like in case 1? Now if the stack space is limited on your platform, then case 2 may not be possible.

Comment: Seems effectively a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238535/c-performance-of-accessing-member-variables-versus-local-variables i.e. use what makes semantic sense & don't worry about premature optimisation until you can prove it'd achieve anything (& be worth a decrease in the sense of the code). Also, yes, Case 1 takes up space in every instance, permanently, even though you just need it temporarily in one function... which probably indicates that's the wrong way to do it. If you only need to use a variable locally, make it a local variable. Anyway, define "advantage": speed or RAM?

Comment: If there is more than one copy of `obj1` there is a big difference in memory. Case 2 will save a lot of memory.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje just one copy

Comment: If the array really isn't capturing state related to `obj1` and doesn't need to last the lifetime of `obj1`, then don't put it in the structure.  Besides being more intuitive, you don't want to carry around an extra 4000 bytes for the object that are largely unused.  With case 2, allocating on the stack is fast and you regain that memory when the function exits.  Just make sure you have enough room in your stack for it, if you're resource constrained.

Answer (score 0):

In first case memory will assigned to array, when ever the object is created.  If array is really not required always, better to use the 2nd Case. All these are purely depend on the program requirement

Answer (score -1):

In case1 array exists as long as the struct/object exists.
In case2 array exists only as long as the procedure is running (so in your main there is smaller memory usage in Case 2).